# Is it safe to pass a lazily initialized object to @synchronized as lock token in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-synchronization

Here's my code snippet:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dict;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (NSMutableDictionary *)dict {
    if (_dict == nil) {
        _dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return _dict;
}

- (void)funcationA {
    @synchronized (self.dict) {
        // do something
    }
}

- (void)functionB {
    @synchronized (self.dict) {
        // do something
    }
}

@end
```

If *functionA* and *functionB* can execute in different threads, I wonder if this **@synchronize()** really works. In my opinion, it could happen when two threads are executing *@synchronized (self.dict)* at the same time before *dict* is initialized, so two instances are created, and the two **@synchronize()** are using two different locks under the hood. This is only my guess and I don't know how to write a demo to demonstrate this.

Comment: You are correct. Not sure how hard it were to demonstrate, as it requires very precise timing. You could use `@synchronized(self)`, possibly wrapping the code in `- (NSMutableDictionary *)dict`.